# C# - How To Retrieve SQL Server Time(7) Into TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, casting, timespan

I'm trying to understand how to retrieve time data from a SQL Server 2012 table column defined as `Time(7)`. I've looked everywhere and have struggled with this. Here is some simple code that I'm using to just try to get it to work.  Can you please help me??

When the code below runs (using Visual Studio 2013) I get the error on the `TimeSpan DBStartTime...` line:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I have no idea how to fix this.

```
var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TaktBoardsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString); 

SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ScheduleDetail WHERE ScheduleID = " + lstShifts.SelectedValue;
comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
comm.Connection = conn;

SqlDataReader reader;

conn.Open();
reader = comm.ExecuteReader(); 

while (reader.Read())
{
    TimeSpan DBStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["StartTime"]).TimeOfDay;
    TimeSpan DBEndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(reader["EndTime"]).TimeOfDay;

    // Add more coding once this works.
}

conn.Close();
```

Comment: You make [SQL injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp). Use this code to solve it: `cmd.Parameters.Add("UserId", UserId.Text)` with this query `SELECT * FROM ScheduleDetail WHERE ScheduleID = ?` but then you must use [oledb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLE_DB)

Comment: @Hein that is not the correct method to use.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: why not?

Comment: @Hein The SQL Server provider doesn't use `?`, it uses named placeholders. You should use eg `@userId` as the parameter name in the SQL statement *and* as the parameter name. `?` is used in OLEDB

Comment: @Hein The overload you are using is `SqlParameterCollection.Add Method (String, Object)` [which is marked as obsolete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9dd8zze1(v=vs.110).aspx), also you need to use `@SomeName` not `?` for Microsoft SQL.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `Convert.ToDateTime` the reader is already returning a Timespan, just do a direct cast.

```
    TimeSpan DBStartTime = (TimeSpan)reader["StartTime"];
    TimeSpan DBEndTime = (TimeSpan)reader["EndTime"];
```

---

Also, not related to your problem, but you are not using a parameter for `ScheduleID = " + lstShifts.SelectedValue;`, you really should. Nor are you using `using` statements, when your code does throw a exception you are not getting your connection objects closed.

```
var cnnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TaktBoardsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cnnString))
using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
{
    comm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM ScheduleDetail WHERE ScheduleID = @ScheduleID";
    comm.Parameters.Add("@ScheduleID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = lstShifts.SelectedValue;
    comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    comm.Connection = conn;

    conn.Open();

    using(SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
             TimeSpan DBStartTime = (TimeSpan)reader["StartTime"];
             TimeSpan DBEndTime = (TimeSpan)reader["EndTime"];
            // Add more coding once this works.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Scott!!  You don't know how much anguish you've now resolved.  :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I hit submit to respond to your comment at the top before I was done typing, I have finished it with the parmameter.

Comment: I've used parameters before but usually in an insert.  Can you suggest what you'd change my code to with a parameter?

Comment: 1) It allows for [Execution Plan Caching](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx) which will boost your performance, 2) It gives you extra security and prevents [Sql Injection](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/25684/2221). Now if `SelectedValue` is a `int` like I guessed you ***might*** be safe, but if you use a parameter you ***know*** you are safe.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, just want to clarify something, my understanding is that you need to have using statements on unmanaged code which in this case is the SqlConnection class, the other 2 using statements are containing manage code elements so only need disposing of if you don't have direct access to the SqlConnection as using doesn't close the connection just disconnects if from the object graph so the garbage collector and identify its not in use anymore (and the GC will then close the connection. is that not correct?

Comment: @MikeT The reader needs to be disposed as that marks the reader as "Complete", If you where going to issue a 2nd command on the same connection it would fail if the reader was not closed/disposed. The SqlCommand you could get away with not disposing it however internally when you dispose of the class it sets the internal object [`_cachedMetaData`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,6d1f148f36c73572) null which allows the GC to have shorter paths to detect roots and allow it to run marginally faster.

Comment: @MikeT As to your comment *"and the GC will then close the connection"*, the GC is not deterministic, it is very possible that you could write a program that will never have a Gen 3 collection. If the connection got in to the Gen 3 pool it may stay open for a very long time, keeping the connection resource tied up. ADO.NET (the underlying thing SqlConnection runs on) uses [connection pooling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399543(v=vs.110).aspx) but the connection does not return to the pool till it is closed or disposed.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, thanks for that, i was aware of the pooling issue which is why i was told you always have to close the connection and dispose of it as if you haven't closed it and the GC doesn't dispose quickly then the pool remains locked until the GC disposes

Comment: @MikeT Calling Dispose calls Close, you don't need to do both. ADO.NET actually works best with many short lived connections due to the connection pooling. The best thing to do is just use `using` statements and then you don't need to worry about the GC or remembering to call `Close()`. Also my prevous comment did not have the correct link to [`_cachedMetaData`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlCommand.cs,53ad9885e5a8fc48), that should go directly to the Dispose method of SqlCommand

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The link is to SQLCommand not SqlConnection, however selecting the correct class shows that Dispose(); isn't overridden from Component, however this topic is getting very technical and off topic so i think we should leave it here

Answer (score 1):

I think you have miss understood what a DateTime and TimeSpan are
a DateTime is a certain time of the day ie 8PM on the 4th July
where as a TimeSpan is a duration ie 9hours

because if this if you do "8PM on the 4th July" - "3PM on the 4th July" you will get a TimeSpan of 5Hours, therefore if you convert directly from the database Time of 7PM to a dateTime you will get "7PM on 1st january 0001" which is completely useless. instead go straight to timespan though in this case you are slightly handicapped by the fact by the fact TimeSpan isn't a default Convertion type in Convert so you need to use the old style convertion using brackets

```
if(reader["EndTime"] is TimeSpan)
    DBEndTime = (TimeSpan)reader["EndTime"];
```